# Keep caret same position after removing charecter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, caret

I have simple react input component that accepts only numbers, each keyboard input i check inputs and return validated entries only, after 3rd character I add `-` character to the input. everything works fine but when i edit / remove one char from first third character my caret jumps to last position its annoying, how can i keep caret at the same position.

[Link to working example](https://m56jn2rjp9.codesandbox.io/)

My input component

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {value} = this.state
        return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this._onChange}/>
        </div>
        )
    }

    _onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({value: this._validate(e.target.value)})
    }

    _validate(string){
        return new Input(string)
            .filterNumbersOnly()
            .addSeparator()
            .getString()
    }

}

export default App;
```

Here is my string validation class

```
export default class Input{
    constructor(string){
        this.string = string
    }

    filterNumbersOnly(){
        const regex = /(\d)/g
            ,strArray = this.string.match(regex)
        this.string = strArray ? strArray.reduce((a,b) => { return `${a}${b}` }, '') : ''
        return this
    }

    addSeparator(){
        const charArray = this.string.split('')
        this.string =  charArray.reduce((a,b,index) => {
            if(index > 2 && index < 4) {
                return `${a}-${b}`
            }
            return `${a}${b}`
        }, '')
        return this
    }

    getString(){
        return this.string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way if you could preserve the selection range and element target and then apply it after the set state i.e on set state callback like this:

```
 _onChange = (e) => {
        var r =[e.target.selectionStart,e.target.selectionEnd];
        var el = e.target;
        this.setState({value: this._validate(e.target.value)},()=>{
            //just to make sure you extend cursor in case of - addition
            if (r[1] === this.state.value.indexOf("-")+1)
              r[1]++;
            el.setSelectionRange(r[0], r[1]);
        })
    }
```

Sample url https://codesandbox.io/s/628q1rvnl3

Answer (score 0):

It resolve all my problem, init selection in callback setState

```
let el = ev.target                
this.setState({
    sum: value
}, () => {
    el.setSelectionRange(1, 1)
})
```